# MySQL complex merge of two tables with different date format

Tags: mysql, date, merge, tabular

I have a MySQL table like this fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ae5c/15

And the other has different from an API: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7946e/1

What I want to have is a result (weekly) like this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| date     | action   | position | name       | day        | ID         |
+----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|17.06.2013| holiday  | home     | Winkler,Mr.| Monday     | 0          |
|18.06.2013| holiday  | home     | Winkler,Mr.| Tuesday    | 1          |
|19.06.2013| work     | NYC      | Winkler,Mr.| Wednesday  | 2          |
|20.06.2013| work     | NYC      | Winkler,Mr.| Thursday   | 3          |
|21.06.2013| work     | NYC      | Winkler,Mr.| Friday     | 4          |
|22.06.2013| work     | NYC      | Winkler,Mr.| Saturday   | 5          |
|23.06.2013| weekend  | home     | Winkler,Mr.| Sunday     | 6          |
+----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Does anyone of you have experience with anything like this?

I do not get do merge them correctly because of the missing dates in the second table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one  i have joined your tables and noticed that `DATETIME` field having type `text` which is too bad to save the date as text this should be as `date` or `datetime` but however i have used [**STR_TO_DATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert as date , In below query i have used the left join for `mydates` and also used CASE to make custom conditions , you have to provide one date so to get the records of [***WEEK***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) for that date

```
SELECT md.`mydate`,
(CASE WHEN g.`ACTION` IS NULL  &&  DAYNAME(md.`mydate`) ='Sunday'  THEN 'Weekend' 
WHEN g.`ACTION` ='0' THEN g.`ACTIONTEXT` 
WHEN  g.`ACTION` IS NULL THEN 'holiday' 
ELSE 'holiday' END) `action` 
,
(CASE WHEN g.`POSITION` IS NULL THEN 'Home' ELSE g.`POSITION` END)`position` ,
g.`DRIVERNAME`,DAYNAME(md.`mydate`),g.`ID`  FROM `mydates` md 
LEFT JOIN `geoimportroot` g ON (md.`mydate`=  STR_TO_DATE(g.`DATETIME`, "%d.%m.%Y")  )
WHERE WEEK(md.`mydate`)= WEEK('2013-06-17')
```

[***Here is your fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/130d8e/1)

I hope this is what you are looking for